# pass taxonomy term value to content type

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, uri

on view page there would be a 2 level taxonomy term listed as menu.
If i select any leaf taxonomy term for e.g (mobile -> mobile accessories) whereas mobile accessories is the leaf taxonomy term.

Then a content type page say "ABC" should be called having the (mobile -> mobile accessories) as default field value.

Am using conditional field module, which will display only the required field related to the taxonomy term being selected.

Thanks you in advance....

Comment: Do you have the taxonomy set up as a hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply..
Yes, taxonomy is set up as a hierarchy and using Hierarchical select module... But not mandatory to use hierarchical select module.. Ur solution is most welcomed.. Am in DAMN need..

Comment: On which version of Drupal is this? Taxonomy in D7+ works differently to that in D6-